# auto-increment doesnt return id in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I wanted to increment the id whenever a new document is added. But when I use the following code, neither fieldnum nor _id is autoincrementing.And I couldn't find the fieldnum . I know this is a lame question but can anyone please help me on this?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    pureautoinc = require('mongoose-pureautoinc');
var connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost/myDatabase");
pureautoinc.init(connection);
var bookSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    genre: String,
    publishDate: Date
});
bookSchema.plugin(pureautoinc.plugin,{model : 'Book',field :'fieldnum'});
var Book = connection.model('Book',bookSchema);
var book1 = new Book({title : "goutham", genre : "comedy", publishDate : new Date()});
book1.save();
var book2 = new Book({title : "goutham1", genre : "comedy", publishDate : new Date()});
book2.save();
console.log(book1,book2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's creating the `fieldnum` atrribute, and it's also autoincrementing it. If you check your saved objects through your `mongodb` console, calling `db.books.find()`, you'll see that the attribute was created.

The problem in your code is that you're not passing any callback to the `save` calls, so your're calling `console.log(book1, book2)` before they return. What you should've done to see the persisted objects:

```
var logIfSaved = function (error, doc) {
  if (error) throw Error(error);
  console.log(doc);
};

var book1 = new Book({title : "goutham", genre : "comedy", publishDate : new Date()});
book1.save(logIfSaved);
var book2 = new Book({title : "goutham1", genre : "comedy", publishDate : new Date()});
book2.save(logIfSaved);
```

Now, passing a callback to your `save` calls, you'll log the objects only after they're saved.